Git lfs, track folder at any position within the project
When using following .gitattributes, does it also track any folder named "models" regardless its location within the project?
models/** filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

I though so, but I have the following structure:
.
├── README.md
├── app
│   └── models
│       └── teste_models_2.txt
└── models
    ├── teste_models_1.txt
    └── teste_models_3.txt

3 directories, 4 files

and lfs is only tracking the "models" folder at the project root. git lfs ls-files outputs:
f6b7636768 * models/teste_models_1.txt
5001fc30e4 * models/teste_models_3.txt

